# ng-change triggered before value is updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a form which needs to save data each time something is changed. I've used `ng-change` on all form elements to trigger a form validation and a save. However in case of radio buttons, `ng-change` is triggered before the actual value is updated, thus resulting in an invalid form on the first try, and an outdated form all subsequent times.

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rkdzgcn/2/) to illustrate this. The console prints out whether the form is valid or not. The same applies if I were to print the value of `$scope.form.test.$modelValue`.

```
// HTML
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="test" value="yes" required ng-change="checkRadios()" /> Yes<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="test" value="no" required ng-change="checkRadios()"/> No
  </form>
</div>

// JS
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.test = null;
    $scope.checkRadios = function(){
        console.log($scope.form.test.$modelValue);
    }
}
```

Is my logic faulty, is this a valid bug, or does it work as expected? In the last case, what can I do to always get the actual value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a delay to get the updated value of the `$scope.form`, so it is possible to achieve by using `$timeout`

http://jsfiddle.net/loen22/w7dpx57f/

```
$scope.checkRadios = function(){
  $timeout(function () {
    console.log($scope.form.$valid);
  });
}
```

Comment: I usually avoid using timeouts in cases like this, because they seem hacky, but unfortunately I don't see an alternative, so I'm going to go ahead and implement this. Thanks.

Comment: Actually $timeout queues the callback to run on the next digest cycle, so in the current digest cycle the `$scope.form` update is performed, this makes $timeout be less hacky :)